# Passing database object in PHP functions

Tags: php, database, class, pdo, singleton

Not sure if appropriate but here goes.

I have build a small system for online reservations of slots during a day.
Because I use a database and connect to it all the time to run some queries I created a simple class that creates the connection (using PDO) and running queries (preparing them, running them, if an error happens it manages and logs it, etc).

I also use AJAX a lot so basically, when a user wants to register, log in, get the schedule of the day, book a slot, cancel a booking and so one, I use AJAX to load a script that goes through the procedure for each action (I will call this the AJAX script) and in that script I include the relevant script that contains all the functions needed (I will call this the function script). The idea is that the AJAX script just gets the parameters, calls a list of functions which based on the results returns some kind of response. The function script contain all the code, that builds the queries, and gets the database data, makes any checks, creates new objects if needed etc.

The way I was doing it was that in the start of the AJAX script I create my database class instance and then just pass it through to the functions as needed (Mostly because I started with all the code in the AJAX script and then moved to creating the separate function in the second script and just leaving the minimum code needed to guide the action)...

So my question is, is it a good/better practise to remove the database class instance all together from the AJAX script and instead include the database class script in the function script and just instantiate inside each function? I am wondering about the idea of creating connections along with each function and then destroying them (most of the functions are small and usually have one query or two , there are some that have a lot in which i use transactions).

I have read about using a singleton as well but I am not sure how it would work in the web. My understanding is if there 2 users logged in the site and both try to fetch the schedule, then the script is called once for each user, making a diffrent connection - even if the parameters of the connection are the same ( I have a guest_user with select/insert/update privileges in my database). So even if I had a singleton, then I would still have two separate connection in the above scenario right? Hoever the difference is as I have it now I would have two connections, open for 1 sec but with change I ask about I would have 10 for each user let's say (10 functions called) for 100ms each time... Is this good or bad? Can it cause problems (if I extrapolate this to real world, with say 1000 users, usually 20-40 at the same time on the site)...

What about security, can these connections be used to steal the data that are exchanged (okay this is farfetched and not really an issue, the data are relatively harmless, other than phones but...)

Comment: The main reason to write your own database class would be to wrap PHP's functionality, to create a certain degree of abstraction. This is what PDO itself does as well. The reason to make it a singleton, it to have the connection easily available for the entire application. Whether singletons are good is a different discussion, which is too broad by itself (hint: it is not. A singleton is basically a global variable).

Comment: PHP runs a script in response to a request. The script runs, creates its own objects in its own space and terminates when the response is done. You can cache MySQL connections for performance (persistent connection), but that still doesn't mean you can share the database object itself. The security question is completely unclear to me, and overall I think your question is very broad and many parts of it are highly opinionated.